# Getting keyerror from sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree, gridsearchcv

I am trying to implement decision tree classifier using **GridSearchCV**. After implementation i tried to to access **cv_results_.mean_train_score** but i am getting key error.

```py
    tuned_parameters = [{'max_depth': [1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100, 150, 250, 500, 750, 1000], 
                         'min_samples_split' : [5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 150, 250, 500]}] 
    cv_timeSeries = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=4).split(X_train)
    base_estimator = DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight='balanced') 
    gsearch_cv = GridSearchCV(estimator=base_estimator, 
                              param_grid=tuned_parameters, 
                              cv=cv_timeSeries, 
                              scoring='roc_auc', 
                              n_jobs=-1)
    gsearch_cv.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

When i am trying to access all the keys of gsearch_cv, i am unable to find dict key mean_train_score.

Answer (score 11):

add the parameter following parameter in GridSearchCV

GridSearchCV(return_train_score=True)

Answer (score 3):

Could you please post the code that generates the error?

mean_train_score is a key of cv_results_ so to get his values you shall:

```
gsearch_cv = GridSearchCV(estimator=base_estimator, 
                          param_grid=tuned_parameters, 
                          cv=cv_timeSeries, 
                          scoring='roc_auc', 
                          return_train_score=True,
                          n_jobs=-1)
gsearch_cv.fit(X_train, y_train)
gsearch_cv.cv_results_['mean_train_score']
```

You can find a complete example on the sklearn page https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html

Comment: Hi *@Matteo*, I tried to run example given in above link, still there is no key named _mean_train_score_. Keys collection contain only score related to **test** not **train**

Comment: Hi, could you please post then your output of 'gsearch_cv.cv_results_.keys()'

Comment: `sorted(clf.cv_results_.keys())`  **output**

['mean_fit_time',
 'mean_score_time',
 'mean_test_score',
 'param_C',
 'param_kernel',
 'params',
 'rank_test_score',
 'split0_test_score',
 'split1_test_score',
 'split2_test_score',
 'split3_test_score',
 'split4_test_score',
 'std_fit_time',
 'std_score_time',
 'std_test_score']

Comment: try to run:                                                                                                  gsearch_cv = GridSearchCV(  return_train_score=True,                                              estimator=base_estimator, 
param_grid=tuned_parameters, 
cv=cv_timeSeries, 
scoring='roc_auc', 
n_jobs=-1)

Answer (score -1):

Try the following change:

```py
gsearch_cv = GridSearchCV(estimator=base_estimator,
                          param_grid=tuned_parameters,
                          cv=cv_timeSeries,
                          scoring='roc_auc',
                          return_train_score=True,
                          n_jobs=-1,
                          return_train_score=True)
```